# How to comsume RESTFull webservice hosted on Tomcat in Android?

Tags: android, web-services, rest, tomcat, jersey

I wrote a rest service and deployed on tomcat. And created client using Jersey in another java project and consume it worked !!.

But now I am using same client on AndrOid it fails even after i referenced all necessary libraries.

I get following error:
at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:119)

Please help. I want to post as well as get complex type to/from server.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: You didn't include the message you get with the error, just at what line it was thrown.

Comment: You might look at Spring RestTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

android doesnt support javax libraries at all
you need to use the android native libraries
read this: [Android network operations](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html)